# How do I remove snowy or blue lines from google chrome when browsing certain websites?

Tags: google-chrome

When viewing websites in chrome I'm getting annoying blue lines across the screen. Looks like snow if it were blue, it changes as you scroll. Only happens in google chrome.

Answer (score 0):

If you ever get snowy or garbled blue lines across your screen in google chrome, go into your chrome preferences,  go to Default Browser -> Click Advanced -> Under system turn off
"Use Hardware Acceleration when available", and click reload. That fixed it for me.